# How to change user name on Cygwin

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, user-accounts

When I first installed and ran Cygwin,
my username and PC name appeared at the beginning of the prompt, like

```
Johm@John-PC ~
```

The problem is, there was a typo in the account name when I first installed Windows 7
and it still remains in Cygwin.

I changed the Windows account name, changed the corresponding folder name and corrected the relevant registry (`Local Machine->Microsoft->Windows NT->Current Version->profile list`).
Then I deleted Cygwin, including its registries, re-downloaded it, and installed it again.

But the old wrong user name still remains. How can I correct this?

Comment: This answer on StackOverflow should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225764/safely-change-home-directory-in-cygwin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try editing the /etc/passwd file, the username can be changed in the first field. Avoid using spaces in the name

Comment: Could you tell me how can I edit /etc/passwd file? I'm not familiar with cygwin commands

Comment: I believe you would type `nano /etc/passwd` (you must run Cygwin as an administrator) and you would edit it from the command line. Then you press `CTRL` + X, then `Y` and finally the enter key to save it.

Comment: I had to `mkpasswd > /etc/passwd` and then edit the line beginning with my firstname to match the desired cygwin username.   It was my firstname because on Windows 10, I used a microsoft account as my windows login.